# Loop through Struts iterator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2

I have a list of items (from a backend db) that is dynamically populated using Struts iterator in a .jsp file. The file also has a JavaScript function to insert a new item into the database. But before I do the insert, I need to check that the item ID (which is a unique key) does not already exist. I've tried something like this:

**item.jsp**

```
<s:form name="ItemForm" id="ItemForm" action="Item.action">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <s:iterator value="itemForm.allItems">
          <tr class="pointer" align="left">
            <td align="left"><s:property value="itemID" /></td>
            <td align="left"><s:property value="itemName" /></td>
          </tr>
        </s:iterator>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <label>Item ID</label>
    <s:textfield name="itemForm.itemID" id="itemID"/>

    <label>Item Name</label>
    <s:textfield name="itemForm.itemName" id="itemName"/>

    <button type="button" id="insertBtn" onclick="insertItem()">Add New Item</button>
</s:form>

<script>
function insertItem() {
    // check if item already exist
    var inputID = document.getElementById("itemID").value;
    var allItems = $("#itemForm.allItems"); // doesn't work - allItems remain undefined
    for (var item in allItems) {
        if (item["itemID"] == inputID) {
            alert("Item ID already exist");
            return; // exit if already exist
        }
    }


// code to insert item

}
</script>
```

How do I use the struts iterator to loop through the list of items in JavaScript? If that's not possible, what would be the recommended way to do it at the JS level?

**EDIT:**

I have also tried the following as per a suggestion.

```
        var inputID = document.getElementById("itemID").value;

        // Get all itemIDs and look for a match
        var matchingElement = $("#itemForm\\.allItems tr td:first-child").filter(function() {
            return this.textContent.trim.value() = inputID; // returns an array of matching values
        });

        console.log("matchingElement length: " + matchingElement.length);

        if (matchingElement.length > 0) {
            alert("Item ID already exist");
            return; // exit if already exist
        }
```

This always returns an empty array (length=0) no matter what itemID I enter. I tried it without the `.filter()` and still got the same results, which leads me to believe that the problem is with obtaining the actual list (i.e the same problem I have originally), and not with the filter.

```
var matchingElement = $("#itemForm\\.allItems tr td:first-child");
```

Here is a sample of the generated html. Apologies if it's not too helpful. I've had to omit and mask a lot of this stuff as it pertains to my work.

```
            <table class="table table-striped jambo_table bulk_action" id="searchResults">
            <caption>Search Results</caption>
            <thead>
              <tr class="headings">
                <th align="left" class="column-title"><a class="sort" href="javascript:sortItem('itemID')">Item ID</th>
                <th align="left" class="column-title"><a class="sort" href="javascript:sortItem('itemName')">Item Name</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="pointer" align="left">
                  <td align="left">BT </td>
                  <td align="left">Item BT</td>
                </tr>   
                <tr class="pointer" align="left">
                  <td align="left">CLM</td>
                  <td align="left">Item CLM</td>
                </tr>   
                <tr class="pointer" align="left">
                  <td align="left">CR </td>
                  <td align="left">Item CR</td>
                </tr>   
                <tr class="pointer" align="left">
                  <td align="left">FA </td>
                  <td align="left">Item FA</td>
                </tr>   
                <tr class="pointer" align="left">
                  <td align="left">HN </td>
                  <td align="left">Item HN</td>
                </tr>   
                <tr class="pointer" align="left">
                  <td align="left">LA  </td>
                  <td align="left">Item LA</td>
                </tr>   
            </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try this:

```
function insertItem() {
    // check if item already exist
    var inputID = document.getElementById("itemID").value;
    $("#searchResults tbody tr td:first-child").each( function( index){
    alert( $(this).text().trim() );
    if ( $(this).text().trim() == inputID) {
        alert("Item ID already exist");
        return; // exit if already exist
    }
    });
// code to insert item
}
```

Or you can access your `allItems` using :

```
var allItems = "<s:property value='itemForm.allItems'/>"
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tested both solutions. I couldn't quite get `var allItems = "<s:property value='itemForm.allItems'/>"` to work (it returns an array much larger than the size of my original list), but the first solution works perfectly.

Comment: at Java side convert `allItems` array to `JSONArray`, then  access It in your javascript code as : `var allItems = "<s:property value='itemForm.allItems'/>"`